# How to parse a 2d array query parameter with Java's Jersey framework

Tags: java, rest, api, multidimensional-array, jersey

Given the following request:

```
GET /schools?primaryKey=1&secondaryKey=11
            &array2d[0][key]=student_number&array2d[0][value]=123456
            &array2d[1][name]=student_name&array2d[1][value]=john
            &searchField=school_name
```

The web API call can send any number of `array2d` name-value pairs.

I need to create a GET web handler to process the request and extract the query parameters into relevant data structures.

Given the data structures, I'd like to query the database and return a response.

How can I deserialize a complex input like this with Jersey?

I have tried the following code:

```
@GET 
@Path("/{primaryKey}{secondaryKey : (/\\d+)?}/{searchField}") 
@Produces("application/json") 

public String getInputs(
@PathParam("primaryKey ") String projectid, 
@PathParam("secondaryKey ") String classid, 
@PathParam("searchField") String searchField)
 throws Exception { #some code here }
```

Comment: can you show any efforts done so far? did you try to get started?

Comment: I am able to read the primaryKey and secondaryKey but unable to read the array2d key value.